# elementtree.parse() not opening file open() will

Tags: python, file-io, xml-parsing

I am trying to write a python script that will open an XML file add some elements and then exit. I can't get element tree to open the file I want. I am able to open the file however with open(). Example code

```
try:
    file = open(projectLocation + "\etc\config\struts-config.xml", 'r')
    print "oppenned file" #this will print
    tree = ET.parse(projectLocation + "\etc\config\struts-config.xml") #this fails
    print "oppenned xml"
except:
    print "could not open " + projectLocation + "\etc\config\struts-config.xml"
    sys.exit()
```

Updating the code to this, for the comment I recieved:

```
    tree = ET.parse(projectLocation + "\etc\config\struts-config.xml")
    print "oppenned xml"
```

this give me the error:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 117, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(projectLocation + "\etc\config\struts-config.xml")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 1205, column 2
```

Comment: Remove the blanket `except` and tell us what exception is being raised. IT is *impossible* for us to start enumerating the various ways XML parsing could have gone wrong here without more details.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I updated the question with the traceback.

Comment: Your XML is malformed; you want to use a XML linter to figure out more detail about how the file is broken, then fix that. This is *not* a Python problem.